# How to check the length of an input String in C

Tags: c, string, string-length

I have this function that check if the string is this:

```
void get_string(char *prompt, char *input, int length)
{
    printf("%s", prompt);                                   
    fgets(input, length, stdin);
    if (input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n')
    {
        int dropped = 0;
        while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n')
        {
            dropped++;
        }
        if (dropped > 0)
        {
            printf("Errore: Inserisci correttamente la stringa.\n");
            get_string(prompt, input, length);
        }
    }else{
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    return;
}
```

With this function I can repeat the input only if the string is longer than `length`.

How can I do if I must check also if the string is shorter?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya That truncates the string by removing the (possible) newline at the end.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my bad, overlooked the condition. Thanks.

Comment: You also need to change your function `type` to provide a meaningful return to indicate success/failure. `char *get_string(...)` would be a good choice allowing your to return `NULL` in case of error, or a valid pointer otherwise. You need to check the **return** of `fgets` - a manual `EOF` can be generated at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is shorter, `fgets` takes care of that. The buffer won't be full, the newline will be placed at the end of the string.

Simply check if `strlen(input) < length` after `fgets`. If that condition evaluates as true, you read less than the maximum of bytes made possible by the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

OP's code is subject to a hacker exploit and may cause *undefined behavior*.

```
// What happens if the first character read is a null character?
fgets(input, length, stdin);
if (input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n')
```

When `fgets()` reads input, an **input** *null character* is not special.  It is read and saved like any other character.

If this pathological case, `input[0] == 0` and `strlen(input) - 1` is `SIZE_MAX`.  `input[SIZE_MAX]` is certainly an access outside array bounds and so *undefined behavior*.

---

A test if `fgets()` did not read all the line is to set the last buffer character to non-zero and later test if it becomes 0.

```
assert(input && length > 1);

input[length - 1] = '\n';

// check `fgets()` return value
if (fgets(input, length, stdin) == NULL) {
  return NULL;
}

if (input[length - 1] == '\0' && input[length - 2] != '\n') {
  // more data to read.
```